# VBA / Excel: click link (<a>) within list (<li>)

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA and hope someone here can help me with the following.

I have an internal web page with a long, unordered HTML list. 
Out of this list I need to find a specific `<li>` tag with a certain ID and then click a link / anchor tag within this list tag.

**The part of the source code looks as follows:**

```
<li id="limitation_type_val531" onclick="show_limitation_subtype(this.id,'150',' SG KYC ','31','3');">
    <img src="/images/icon_sel_tick.gif" id="selected_limitation_type_val531" style="display:none;clear:both;"/>
    <a href="#subtype_section" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000;"> My Target </a>
    <p class="add_arrow_right">&nbsp;></p>
</li>
```

The anchor tag in question does not have a name or ID but is the only anchor tag within this `<li>` tag and has a fixed text (" My Target ").

Can someone tell me how I can simulate a click on this using VBA ?

My thought was to refer to the `<li>` ID as follows but I don't know how to simulate the click on the anchor tag then:

```
Set ObjA = ie.Document.getElementByID("limitation_type_val531").getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
  Set ObjA = ie.Document.getElementByID("limitation_type_val531").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
  ObjA.Click
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks great and is much shorter than expected. :)